# Find polynom p(z) with values in C[S_n] such that p'(z) = \sum_i (Id+(1i))/(z-i) p(z).  [Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equation for S_n]

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider group algebra $C[S_n]$. Take any of its representation $(\pi, V)$ (for example regular). 
Take some complex numbers $z_i$ i=2...n. Denote as usually by $(1i)\in S_n$
 the transpositions of (1) and (i).

**Question** solve the following ODE (it is known that its solution will be polynom p(z) in $z$) :

$ p'(z) = m\sum_{i=2...n} \frac{ Id + \pi( (1i) )}{z-z_i} p (z) $

Here "m" is integer, $p(z)$ is $V$-valued polynom.

The hope is of course for some "nice" formula, although I do not think it is easy question.

---

Well, here should the background... [EDIT - see background below.]
May I kindly apologize and hide the background from you, at least for some hours, I will insert it later, I think that if I put the background you will say "ah famous equation people studied it for many years and everything is known", however I think only 5 people thought on this particular question, and I do not think these thoughts are exhaustive.
So I am afraid background will be demotivating...

---

There are two simple cases where it is easy to get the solution - trivial representation
and sign representation.

For sign representation solution is constant and can be embeded in C[S_n] as p(z) = antisymmetrizer.

For trivial representation the solution is $(symmetrizer) * \prod_i (z-z_i)^2 $.

Even for vector representation in $C^n$ I do not know the nice solution.

### [EDIT] BACKGROUND

This equation is basically [Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knizhnik%E2%80%93Zamolodchikov_equations) (for gl_n (by Schur-Weyl for S_n)).
Much is known about it and about its solutions. However main interest
is focused on the case when m=1/integer - in this case the solutions
are NON-polynomial.

**[Some theory]** 
For the Fuchsian ODE $f'(z) = \sum_i \frac{A_i}{z-z_i} f(z)$,
the obvious necessary condition to have rational (respectively polynomial) solutions
is that eigenvalues of A_i are integers (respectively naturals).
This is clear since near z=z_i solutions have the form  $(z-z_i)^{(A_i)}$,
which is up to change of basis $z^{(\lambda_i)}$, where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A_i$.

One can easily see that for our particular equation these conditions are satisfied.
(Since (1i) is transposition so its eigs are {-1,1}).

Also considering z=infinity we should impose same condition on $\sum_i A_i$.
This sum is actually a Jacus-Murphy element and it is known to have integer eigs,
see  [Why are Jucys-Murphy elements' eigenvalues whole numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83150/why-are-jucys-murphy-elements-eigenvalues-whole-numbers)

But these conditions are not sufficient.
So the first surprise is that for this particular equation it is nevertheless true,
that solutions are polynomial.

This actually can be seen as a corollary of [Drinfeld-Kohno theorem](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Drinfeld-Kohno+theorem), which 
predicts that monodromy of KZ is given by the R-matrix of corresponding quantum
group with q=e^(2\pi i m) =1 for m-integer and R-matrix is degenerated to identity matrix.
However proofs of Drinfeld-Kohno theorem assumes "m" is in general position,
and so this case should be considered specially.

The conditions for Fuchsian equation to be have rational solutions has been analysed:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607555

Meromorphic Solutions of Linear Differential Systems, Painleve type functions

Lev Sakhnovich

**[Related works]**
 http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610383 Polynomial solutions of the Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equations and Schur-Weyl duality Giovanni Felder, Alexander P. Veselov

Moreover they have constructed the polynomial solutions. 
however in terms of some integrals - which may not be the end of the story..

Lev Sakhnovich studied the question in a series of papers:

Explicit calculations are contained in http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609067 Rational solutions of Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov system

http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3873 http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2662

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702404 Rational solutions of KZ equation

We came to this question from the point of view of the Gaudin integrable system.
It appears to be that KZ solutions for m=1 gives rise to the solutions
the so-called GL-oper=BaxterTQequation=quantum spectral curve equation for the Gaudin model. Which encode the information about the Bethe ansatz spectrum of quantum Gaudin
Hamiltonians. See e.g.  http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.2236 page 15 section "4.1.1 Application to the Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equation" 
and references their in.

**Related MO questions**

[Hamiltonians which commute both as operators and as connections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95116/hamiltonians-which-commute-both-as-operators-and-as-connections)

[Compatibility of the KZ connection with operadic composition](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91927/compatibility-of-the-kz-connection-with-operadic-composition)

Comment: I loved the «background will be demotivating» :)

Comment: more we learn less we know :) 

Comment: Sasha, do you know the solution for the group $S_4$, or at least $S_3$ (regular presentation)?

Comment: @Dima, I tried to calculate, as far as I remember for S_3 it was managable, however for S_4 I used Mathematica... Let me write the background and give the references.. Here is reference with explicit calculations for S_4, but the "nice" answer is not yet found http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702404 Rational solutions of KZ equation, case $S_4$
Lev Sakhnovich

Comment: Background - this equation is basically Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equation for the group S_n and can be rewritten as gl_n KZ in vector representation. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610383 Polynomial solutions of the Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov equations and Schur-Weyl duality
Giovanni Felder, Alexander P. Veselov gives solution however in terms of some integrals - which may not be the end of the story... Explicit calculations are contained in http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0609067 Rational solutions of Knizhnik-Zamolodchikov system
L Sakhnovich http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3873  http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2662

Comment: @Alexander: great question.

Comment: Can one express solutions in terms of Jack polynomials?

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam. Thanks for comments.  Why do you think Jacks relevant ? Heh, but that might be great idea: there is Cherednik-Matsuo correspondence between solutions of KZ and spherical functions (which seems related to Jacks), so indeed it might be related... However I tried to apply Cherendik-Matsuo some time ago and failed, I do not remember the reason, it might be in CS-correspondence there is different KZ - some modification of it... Also usual JAcks are scalar valued symmetric polynoms, but we need S_n-valued polynoms covariant with respect to S_n... Any way any comments welcome!

Comment: @Alexander: I was just wondering if Jacks appeared in your problem, but I don't know enough to be able to say that they should appear. I just briefly looked at the Felder-Veselov paper which if I remember correctly mentions Calogero-Moser systems, so I thought there might be some Jacks. For S_n valued: there are recent papers by Dunkl and Luque about vector valued Jacks. I don't know if this can help with your question. One way to know for sure if Jacks are relevent is:
do you polynomials have some clustering properties, ie., vanishing if the the z_i s coalesce according to some partition?

Comment: @Abdelmalek Abdesselam. I do not think that they vanish if z_i coincide. See page 10 formulas upper section 4 in Felder Veselov http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610383v3.pdf there is solution for 3 points. It does not seem to vanish when z_1=z_2 coincide because we have terms in sum for k=0. More simple way to think take all z_i=0. The equation degenerates to p'(z) = (n+JacysMurphy)/(z) p(z) and solution is p(z)= z^(n+JacysMurphy), which does not vanish... may be it is not fully correct argument nevertheless...